# Or in If-Then-Else statement in VBA

Tags: vba

I have this bit of code:

```
If TempVars!CurrentUsername <> "user1" Then
...
Else
...
End If
```

What I'd like to do is add a few more users to the first if statement. I've tried the following:

```
If TempVars!CurrentUsername <> "user1" or "user2" Then
```

and

```
If Not TempVars!CurrentUsername Like "user1" or "user2" Then
```

and

```
If TempVars!CurrentUsername Not Like "user1" or "user2" Then
```

All three attempts yield the same

```
Run-time error '13':
Type mismatch
```

error.

I'm new to VBA, so this could be something simple that I'm simply over-looking. Or is my syntax completely wrong?

Comment: `If TempVars!CurrentUsername <> "user1" and TempVars!CurrentUsername <> "user2" then`

Comment: Thank you! This ended up being the working solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should repeat the variable TempVars!CurrentUsername in your statement.

```
If TempVars!CurrentUsername <> "user1" And TempVars!CurrentUsername <> "user2" Then
```

It uses And because of the <> symbols. To make it work with Or as in your first example you would actually write something like (pseudocode):

```
NOT (X = "1" OR X = "2")
```

But that can also be rewritten to:

```
X <> "1" AND X <> "2"
```

Comment: Could you explain why it needs to be an AND statement between the two conditions? I tried with an OR, and it didn't work. Doing it with an AND, however, did work.

Comment: you have to think about the logic AND means the the user can not be user1 and can not be user2. an OR would always come out try as what ever the value it will not eqaul user1 and user2 at the same time so an OR will always return true in this sitiuatino

Comment: Ohh, I see. That makes sense when you think of it in that manner. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I believe you need to use syntax like:

```
If TempVars!CurrentUsername <> "user1" AND TempVars!CurrentUsername <> "user2" Then
```

Comment: OR didn't work for me. AND did work, however. I wonder why that is.

Comment: That's an odd one @jtchase08.  CurrentUsername can be 'user1' or 'user2' at any point, but pretty sure it could never be 'user1' and 'user2' at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe use SELECT CASE instead?

```
 Select Case TempVars!CurrentUsername

        Case "user1", "user2"
            'Code for these users.

        Case "user3"
            'Code for these other users.

        Case Else
            'Code for any other users not covered.

    End Select
```

Comment: I'll try this method as well. This looks like it would have a lot of versatility. Thanks for the advice!

Comment: This option worked as well. I think this is the one I'll ultimately go with. I like that if I want to add conditions for another set of users, I can easily accomplish that with another case.